# sys.exit(1) does not exit when calling from the signal handler

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a signal handler

```
def signal_handler(signum, stack):
    do_something()
    sys.exit(1)
```

And I register it like this:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal_handler)
```

During the process running, it is possible that some thread may call `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)`
Since I registered this signal at the very beginning of the program, the main thread can grab this signal and call the `signal_handler()`.

However, the `sys.exit(1)` doesn't actually exit the program. I feel like the program goes back to the place where it interrupted by the signal.

I don't understand why this is happening. The reason I want to use `sys.exit` rather than `os._exit` is because I want to trigger the functions registered in `atexit()`.

Are there anyways I can exit the program from the `signal_handler` and also trigger `atexit()` when exiting.

Comment: Could something be catching the `SystemExit` exception?

Comment: Looks like the `atexit` module in both Python 2 & 3 has a `_run_exitfuncs()` function, so you could call it manually and then call `os._exit()`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's really documented what happens when you raise an exception—including `SystemExit`—from within a signal handler. Signal handlers get executed on their own stack in between bytecodes of the main thread of control.

Comment: Also, I notice you tagged this `multithreaded`. If you actually have non-daemon background threads, `sys.exit` is effectively going to `join` them all before exiting (at least on most implementations and platforms; I don't think that's actually documented anywhere).

Comment: A [trivial program that satisfies your description](http://ideone.com/4afyNd) works perfectly well for me. Please reduce your program to the smallest possible program that demonstrates the problem and copy-paste that program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.