# Terminate background python script nicely

Tags: python, macos, process, background-process

I am running a python script in the background using the command `python script.py &`. The script might look like this.

```
import time

def loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Terminated properly")
```

When it comes to terminating the script, I would like to do some cleanup before it is stopped (such as printing "Terminated properly"). If I run as a current process, this would be handled by the `except` statement after a keyboard interrupt.

Using the `kill PID` command means the cleanup is never executed. How can I stop a background process and execute some lines of code before it is terminated?

Comment: you can use `kill -s 2 PID` to send a keyboard interrupt to process `PID`. Um... it should be signal `2` if there is no mistake with my memory.

Comment: `kill` sends a different signal than `KeyboardInterrupt`. By default, it sends `INT (2)`  you can read more about it here http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/kill1.html

Comment: @Vinny signal 9 is SIGKILL...

Comment: Thanks! The `kill -s 2 PID` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use signal module to catch any signals sent to your script via kill.
You setup a signal handler to catch the signal in question that would perform the cleanup.

```
import signal
import time

running = 0

def loop ():
    global running
    running = 1
    while running:
        try: time.sleep(0.25)
        except KeyboardInterrupt: break
    print "Ended nicely!"

def cleanup (signumber, stackframe):
    global running
    running = 0

signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, cleanup)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, cleanup)
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, cleanup)
loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) clause:

```
def loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Terminated properly")
    finally:
        print('executes always')
```

Comment: The `finally` clause does not seem to be executed when using the `kill PID` command.

Comment: Please check this Q/A [How to run one last function before getting killed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930519/how-to-run-one-last-function-before-getting-killed-in-python).