# How to quit a webbrowser session when Python is shutting down?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a python code where I need selenium webbrowser inside one of my classes. I want a selenium session to finish correctly when exiting python

I save the webbrowser variable like a field of my class. To quit the session, I decided to call the `quit()` method of webbrowser inside the `__del__()` method of my class, but it didn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from sys import stderr

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        opts = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
        opts.add_argument('--headless')
        opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        assert opts.headless
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)

    def __del__(self):
        self.browser.quit()
        stderr.write("Browser has been closed correctly!\n")

    # Other methods of my class

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MyClass()
```

If now I call something like `del a`, I get the `Browser has been closed correctly!` message and `chromedriver` disappears from the list of running processes. But if I exit python, I get the error message:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method MyClass.__del__ of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37eb918898>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 158, in quit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 151, in stop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 122, in send_remote_shutdown_command
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

Comment: Maybe using [signal as shown in this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930537/1183506)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104568/494134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of other options:

- Implement `MyClass` as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers).  In its `__exit__` method, quit the browser.  Then use `with MyClass() as mc...`, wherein `__exit__` will be called after the block wraps up
- Use [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) (I would call this overkill) - register instances of `MyClass` to the module's scope; register an exit function that calls `obj.browser.quit()` for each registered instance on program exit.